# Usage of the word "Toward"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In these sentences:

> "I'm kinda sad toward those comment"
>   "I'm kinda 'meh' toward it"

What's the usage of "toward" in this context? Is it even grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Toward**s is defined by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/towards) as:

> with respect to; as regards

---

It's fairly idiomatic. The example:

> "I'm kinda sad towards those comment"

denotes the individuals feelings *with respect to* "those comment[s]" is "sad".

Answer (score 0):

In these examples, the speaker is directing their emotion in the direction of the *comments* or *it* (whatever *it* is.)  It is definitely colloquial and probably not grammatically correct.  However, many people (myself included) do not necessarily pay attention to grammar when speaking informally.